# Odd Mertens function

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, mobius-function

Let $M^*(n)$ be the "odd Mertens function", defined by $M^*(n) = \sum \mu(k)$ for odd $k$, $1 \le k \le n$.

Let $r$ be an odd number. Since $\mu(r)$ is multiplicative, $\mu(2r) = -\mu(r)$ and $\mu(4r) = \mu(8r) = \cdots = 0$.

So splitting $M(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mu(k)$, the standard Mertens function, by even and odd $k$, we only need to consider odd $k$ and even $k$ not divisible by 4. This gives the identity $M(n) = M^*(n) - M^*(n/2)$ or equivalently $M^*(n) = M(n) + M^*(n/2)$, so with a [sublinear algorithm to calculate the Mertens function](https://mathoverflow.net/a/320042/127905) we have our odd Mertens function too.

My question: can we calculate $M^*(n)$ directly (without recursion) in sub-linear time?

Comment: The effort to calculate the sum is only halved this way, this does not make the calculation sublinear , if it was not before.